# Logical Error in column computation on my view

Tags: sql, view

Am trying to create invoice view  base on payment done on `Payment` table.
The `Balance` field on the view is the difference between `AmountDue` and `AmountPaid` fields.
When i insert into payment table balance field shows null.

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[payment](
[AmountDue] [money] NULL,
[AmountPaid] [money] NULL,
[Balance] [money] NULL,
[CheckNumber] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

My view:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[invoice]
AS
SELECT     AmountDue, AmountPaid, Balance AS [[AmountPaid-AmountDue]] AS Bal],   CheckNumber
FROM         dbo.payment
```

GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  Right now you're returning the value of the `Balance` field with a field name of (literally) `"[AmountPaid-AmountDue]] AS Bal"`

I think you want:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[invoice]
AS
SELECT     AmountDue, AmountPaid, AmountPaid-AmountDue AS Balance, CheckNumber
FROM         dbo.payment
```

Although it's unclear how the `Balance` field on the physical `Payment` table should apply since it's ignored in the view.